# Как пробросить нужный бинарник внутри docker-compose виртуалок?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

В `docker-compose.yml` есть виртуалка `workspace` в которой собраны инструменты для разработчиков и админов (`mc`, `curl`, `7z`, `nano`). Но помимо этого - нужен `npm`. Я НЕ хочу пихать туда [скрипт](https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh) по установке, а хочу пробросить `/usr/bin/npm` из [официального контейнера](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). Как это сделать согласно лучшим практикам? Понятно, что как-то через `volumes`, но мы же хотим не какой-то `/my-files/` кидать, а системный каталог(и). Как избежать коллизий перезаписывания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [многофазовую сборку](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) образа:

```
FROM node:latest AS node

FROM alpine:latest

... тут все команды для создания образа как и раньше
... т.е. установка mc, curl, 7z, nano

COPY --from=node /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Чтоб избежать проблем с совместимостью используйте такую же версию базового образа на второй фазе, которая используется в образе node на первой фазе. В примере я использовал alpine:latest, если замените, то и версию образа node нужно поменять.

И еще по терминологии замечание: в докере нет "виртуалок", есть образы и контейнеры. В docker-compose есть сервисы.

Comment: Сорян, что так долго, только добрался. Поехало, но там надо переносить не только npm, но и кучу всего. Механизм понятен, буду пользоваться в других задачах. Ещё раз спасибо.